# Congifuring Red5 Server to run on localhost

Tags: apache, localhost

I just installed the red5 rtmp server on my machine and tried to run the demo. The only thing that i see is "connecting to server" but it never gets connected. I have gone through most of the documentations available online, if anyone of you can help me to configure red5 along with the Apache and make it running, it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Ubuntu [this tutorial](http://haglercomputers.com/2011/09/how-to-install-red5-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts/) is good

[Here is an IIS Tutorial](http://forums.gchats.com/showthread.php/2924-Run-Red5-and-iis-on-port-80)

Comment: thanks for the link.. good one.. but unfortunately I need to configure it on a windows machine.

Comment: I updated my answer to include an IIS tutorial